# CSS class added with .on('click') not visible after first event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to apply a border to a dynamically generated element using $.on('click') and $.addClass(), but the class doesn't seem to be applied on the first click event. Otherwise, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.card', function() {
  var currentSelection = $(this)
  var currentSelectionIndex = $(currentSelection).index()

  $(currentSelection).addClass("selected")

  if (currentSelectionIndex !== previousSelectionIndex) {
    p = $("#searchResponse").children().get(previousSelectionIndex)
    $(p).removeClass("selected")
  }

  previousSelectionIndex = currentSelectionIndex;
});
```

Solution: Assigning `previousSelectionIndex` a value a the beginning of my script and it fixed the issue.

Comment: do you have the markup?

Comment: `currentSelectionIndex !== previousSelectionIndex` This will always be true on the first click. So the first time you will remove the class you just added.

Comment: Seems over complicated. Is `.card` a child of `$("#searchResponse")`? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your question given the information provided.

However, if I understand the problem correctly you have a container element with the `id="searchResponse"` that has many children each with the `class="card"` and you're essentially trying to add `class="selected"` to a particular card when it is clicked ensuring that only one card at a time can be 'selected'. If this is the case..

Select only one card at a time:

`$('#searchResponse').on('click', '.card', function(){
  $('.card.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});`

If you need to select and unselect multiple then try this:

`$('#searchResponse').on('click', '.card', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected';)
});`

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/katrpilar/pen/aQeEMX)

Comment: That worked beautifully and is much shorter than my code, thank you.